# BigQuery DATEADD(MAX(myDate), 1, YEAR) return Function not found: DATEADD; Did you mean date_add? at [6:7]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to find a date, then add a column with that date +1 year. But for some reason I can't use an aggregate function inside the DATEADD method. Does anyone have a workaround for this?

The console returns this error.

```
Function not found: DATEADD; Did you mean date_add? at [6:7]
```

Here is the query.

```
SELECT d.org_id, 
    o.name, 
    SUM(CAST(d.converted_value AS NUMERIC)) as ltv, 
    MIN(won_time) AS first_deal_date, 
    MAX(won_time) AS last_deal_date, 
    DATEADD(MAX(won_time), 1, YEAR) AS churn_date, 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MAX(won_time)) < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) as churn 
FROM deals d
INNER JOIN organizations AS o ON d.org_id = o.id
WHERE d.status = 'won'
GROUP BY d.org_id, o.name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
DATE_ADD(MAX(won_time), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AS churn_date,
```

This assumes that `won_time` is a `date`.  If not, either convert it to a date or use `DATETIME_ADD()` or `TIMESTAMP_ADD()`.

Comment: No matching signature for function DATE_ADD for argument types: TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signature: DATE_ADD(DATE, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART) at [6:7]